# Order Custom Post Type by Custom Field Value

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, order

I'm having trouble getting my custom ordering to work. I'm trying to order a custom post type by a custom field called `feature_order` which is a numeric field (created with Advanced Custom Fields plugin).

Here is the code:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attorneys',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'feature_order',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This has no effect on the actual order. The `feature_order` field was created correctly, and properly stores values, so that's not the issue.

Here's the SQL produced by when I use `echo $query->request`:

```
SELECT wp_posts.*
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta 
ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
WHERE 1=1
AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'feature_order' ) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'attorneys' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order, wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 ASC
```

The problem is the presence of `wp_posts.menu_order` in the `ORDER_BY` clause. When I execute the query directly on the database without this, I get the expected result.

**How do I get WP_Query to stop ordering by `wp_posts.menu_order`?**

Alernatively, how can I instantiate a WP_Query object with an SQL string?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I don't believe ordering by `menu_order` is a default behavior for WordPress, it should be `post_date` if anything which leads me to believe a plugin or a `pre_get_posts` hook is adding this in somewhere. I would start by disabling all plugins ( except the absolute necessary ) and then maybe searching the theme `pre_get_posts`.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Thanks for your help. You're correct. It was a plugin forcing ordering by `menu_order`. The plugin is called Post Types Order (https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-types-order/), and this effect can actually be turned off in the settings. If you would put your response as an answer I would mark it as correct and you'd get a fancy, green checkmark ;)